# How can I give camera permissions to external app in Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, permission, camera

I use a Macbook Air 13'' with M2 chip with MacOS Monterrey 12.6.5 and I'm trying to give Camera permissions for Chrome (Google-Meet).
In System preferences > Security & Privacy, I obtain the message "Apps that have requested access to your camera will appear here" where apps like Google Chrome or Zoom should be expected with a Check box.

[image]

I must say that the camera works with Facetime so it must be a software related problem.

Comment: Did Chrome ever asked to use the Camera? Also, have you checked in **System Preferences > Chrome** that Camera is enabled?